# How can I use the selected option from drop down menu to query my database ?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PDO to interact with my database. How can I use the input a user selects to query my database. This is what I have so far. I store the selected option as a variable, but it actually is not being captured. What can I do to fix this?

```
  echo <<<FORMSTART
  <form name= "name" method= "post">
   <select name = "name" onChange="document.topic_list.submit()">
   <option value = "None">Select name</option>
FORMSTART;

    $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT DISTINCT name from users");

    //populate drop down menu
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

        echo "<option value= '" . $row['name'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
    }

    //End form for drop down menu
    echo <<<FORMEND
</select>

</form>
FORMEND;

    $selected_name = $_POST["name"];
    //This prints here but when I try to use this variable later it doesnt print anything
    echo "$selected_name Selected";
```

Comment: I'm voting this as a typo, since you used the same name attributes. `<form>` does not use name attributes, maybe with JS but not in pure PHP. Only form elements do.

Comment: Even when I do not have the same name attributes I have the same outcome

Comment: "<form> does not use name attributes," name attribute within the form tag is perfect valid html. Beside topicstarter is using `<select name = "name"` which is correct  that's the value that will be sended to PHP and fill up `$_POST["name"]` @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: check for errors then, via php and the query

Comment: @RaymondNijland Look at `<form name= "name" method= "post">` and then `<select name = "name"` < what is that; *different?*

Comment: Doesn't matter they won't override other within the browser @FunkFortyNiner.. Besides `form name= "name"` is never sended to PHP annyhow.

Comment: the names do not make a difference @FunkFortyNiner ... however, do you know how I can fix the problem I am having?

Comment: again; check for errors via php's error reporting and https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php. Things such as using `var_dump()` and looking at the HTML source are also valid debugging methods.